# The general format of the nonlinear algebraic equations of the third order

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics

In a third-order nonlinear algebraic equation system;is it possible to have two unknowns of the order of three in any equations?

[equation system with four unknowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfiWc.jpg)

Comment: `is it possible to have two unknowns of the order of three in any equations?` Sure, why not?

Comment: Of course. The order of an equation is the highest sum of the exponents. In the third equation, there are nine terms of cubic order.

Comment: Thank you for your help.In general,in a third-order non-linear algebraic equation system, how many third-order term are there in each equation?

Comment: dxiv,thank you for your response.